# CSS won't work through Heroku when routed through PHP

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am uploading a bootstrap template through Heroku.  The name of the template is: Brushed. http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/

I route to the home page through a php file with the following code:

```
<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>
```

Everything works in the emulator on cloud9, however, when I upload it to Heroku only my HTML shows up without any of my CSS.  Does anyone have any idea of what I can do?

Here is a link to my site: https://mariatorres.herokuapp.com/

It is not a rails app, just a static bootstrap template.

Comment: THis is the code I use: <?php include_once("home.html"); ?>

Comment: The URLs to the CSS resources are broken. Example: https://mariatorres.herokuapp.com/_include/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome's Code Inspector and go to Network, and try to reload your webpage, you will see that the .css files are 404 not found... you can reproduce the same if you load your webpage, open it's source and see (and try to open) the .css links.. you will see that they are not found. To fix this, where you load the .css files try to use the full path of the CSS, or if you rewrite/route your paths, fix the path to the CSS files..

Only by showing us the include statement, is not enough..